# how to access $_SESSION var from php to python

Tags: python, php, mysql, sql, backend

I am using sql in python. I want to be able to select sql items in python based on the active user's email when the user accesses the page.

My plan was to use $_SESSION($email) to access the email of the active user. I then assign it to a var $email. Then, I have to take $email from the php file to a python file where it can be used to select.

Essentially, there are two questions here. How do I transfer the contents of $email? How do I use that in the SELECT statement in the python file to access elements with the same email?

Here is my code below:

php

```
 <?php
                
              $email = $_SESSION['email'];
                
              
              $command = escapeshellcmd('C:/Python38/python.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/Ensemble/login/test.py' . $email); 
              $output = shell_exec("$command 2>&1");
              print($output);
             
              
            ?>
```

python

```
import sys

email = sys.argv[1]

db_connection = sql.connect(host='localhost', database='questionbank', user='root', password='')

print (email)

training_set = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM mathanswers", con=db_connection)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a python file to query a mysql database? It would be a lot simpler to do this from php. Btw, shellexecute or any similar solution may work academicslly, but will not scale in a real-life application. You would need some  background worker solution (redis, celery, rabbitmq) to make this scalable.

Comment: @Shadow because I have an algorithm after the given code in python to take the sql database and analyze it

Comment: @Shadow why isnt shell_exec usable

Comment: I did not write it was not usable. It is not scalable. Unless your python script uses some kind of a machine learning or NLP algorithm, I sugges you implement the logic in php. You are going to face enormous grief when you want to move it into production a scale it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check the space for arguments of python

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('C:/Python38/python.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/Ensemble/login/test.py<space here>' . $email);
```

then check if python catches it by making a file to write the logs.

check this
[link](https://stackabuse.com/writing-to-a-file-with-pythons-print-function/)

Comment: While this solution may work in an academic environment, it will not scale in real-life circumstances.